# Rails app on Heroku not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, asset-pipeline

My js is not working on Heroku. As you can see in (the page is loaded but no content is showed)

```
www.nmusicjungle.heroku.com
```

I guess the problem is the asset pipeline, destroying my js files

Everything works fine on localhost, and you can see the result here

```
www.musicjungle.com.br
```

I even tried to use `config.assets.enabled = false` in `application.rb`, but nothing changed on heroku.

At first I was trying to let heroku compile the assets, but heroku failed. So I did `assets:precompile` on local machine (with no errors) and Heroku accepted the manifest file
I'm using Ruby 2 and Rails 4

Edit: Just to Add a bizarre behavior, the website is partly loaded on my tablet... lol

Comment: did you commit changes and repush to heroku after you changed application.rb?

Comment: What happens if you run 'heroku run rake assets:precompile'?

Comment: @PeterdeRidder : After some typos (css and js) corrections, heroku was able to precompile my assets

Comment: @dax Yes I repushed, if you visit now the URL, the js and css were compiled by heroku.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
config.assets.enabled = false
```

is not what you want.

Steps to troubleshoot, compile your assets locally with

```
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```

Test your app locally before pushing

```
rails s -e production
```

Most likely you will want to play with the following settings in your "my environment".rb file

```
  config.serve_static_assets = true

 # Compress JavaScripts and CSS
 config.assets.compress = false

 # Don't fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed
 config.assets.compile = false

 # Generate digests for assets URLs
 config.assets.digest = true
```

Comment: Thanks for the tips TheIrishGuy, doing all these steps I was able to found some minor mistaker on two files (typos in js and css). I corrected them and the assets:precompile for the production env was ok. But still nothing is loaded after
    rails -s e production

Comment: Btw I was even able to use Heroku to compile the assets this time

Comment: Everything is working now, a tip for the future: If you're going to use a someone else .js, make sure there is no errors on it, debug it on Chrome! Thanks @TheIrishGuy for the tips to track my bug